# CollectionFS with mongo update command in Meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my meteor.js application, I am trying to update a group's picture by using CollectionFS.

```
var groupimage = Images.insert(file);
Groups.update(groupId, {$set: { photo: groupimage }}, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                // display the error to the user
                throwError(error.reason);
            } else {
                console.log('mongo document new');
                console.log(Groups.findOne({_id:groupId}));

            }
        });
```

This does not work, it gives this error:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking '/groups/update': ReferenceError: throwError is not defined
at http://localhost:3000/client/views/groups/editgroup/editgroupgeneral/editgr…dropzoneeditgroupgeneral.js?a1c6bb6d6c464c579ca4a82ca9f92775df17f5c5:39:21
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?9213dc77ff40001575341a02827a8f1ed3200d98:531:9)
at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?47d1d2b71177463dc159606cf930e44b9e3337f6:831:22)
at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3802:12)
at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3822:10)
at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:4831:9)
at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3667:12)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?     32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:2710:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
```

But when I insert instead of update, everything is working perfectly. This works.

```
 var groupimage = Images.insert(file);
        Groups.insert({
            name: 'My Group',
            photo: groupimage
        });
```

What is the problem with my update? Thank you.

**Edit**

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking '/groups/update': Error
at http://localhost:3000/client/views/groups/editgroup/editgroupgeneral/editgr…dropzoneeditgroupgeneral.js?c24e8998d12b9aaa84912c2e87ec327e47277070:39:27
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?9213dc77ff40001575341a02827a8f1ed3200d98:531:9)
at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?47d1d2b71177463dc159606cf930e44b9e3337f6:831:22)
at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3802:12)
at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3822:10)
at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:4831:9)
at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:3667:12)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?32d6f3870045baedecfa7c0d90861ead2810da37:2710:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
```

**Edit 2**

```
errorClassdetails: undefinederror: 409errorType: "Meteor.Error"message: "MongoError: not okForStorage [409]"reason: "MongoError: not okForStorage"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Middle
```

Comment: How and where is the function `throwError` implemented?

Comment: I did not implement it by myself

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use Meteor's [error method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_error) instead:

```
 throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.reason);
```

Comment: Wow, explicit... could you maybe `console.log(error)` instead, and check the output?

Comment: i did. Check edit 2. It is giving mongodb error, but the weird part is that it is not giving any error for inserting. So maybe, it has only problem with update command.